# the meaning of "has some go to steps for"

Tags: meaning

*David Ospina: A reluctant showman but as an experienced member of the squad has some **go to steps for** when he is called upon.*

[Source](https://twitter.com/SimonEdwardsSAF/status/1139920803871502336?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1139920803871502336&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sport.cz%2Ffotbal%2Fostatni%2Fclanek%2F1115786-messi-znovu-na-kolenou-kolumbie-zaskocila-favorita.html%23hp-sez).

Can you clarify to me the precise meaning of the bolded passage? I thought that it is some sort of an idiom but have not found anything on the internet.. I presume that the author wants to say that Ospina is still a useful member of the team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of [*go to*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20to) in this sense is as follows:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2** : regularly or repeatedly chosen or employed for reliably good results
>   // O'Neal's *go-to* move has become a soft jump hook, which he can shoot with either hand.
>   — Chris Ballard
>   // While mozzarella may be the *go-to* cheese for pizza, … blue cheese … can also be great.
>   — Sam Gugino
>   // A waitress came by and Reacher ordered his *go-to* breakfast, which was coffee plus a short stack of pancakes with eggs, bacon, and maple syrup.
>   — Lee Child

Note that *go-to* is often hyphenated rather than left open as in the example sentence in the question.

In short, the passage is saying that over his years of experience he has come to develop certain steps (*go-to steps*) that have always produced good results for him, so he keeps on using them. They are steps that are part of his normal repertoire or, to use another idiom, in his *bag of tricks*.